# Android populate Spinner with 2 ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, spinner

How can I populate a spinner with 2 ArrayList? For example: I have 2 arrayList

```
<string-array name="month">
<item>Gen</item>
<item>Feb</item>
<item>Mar</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="monthN">
<item>0</item>
<item>01</item>
<item>02</item>
</string-array>
```

In the spinner I would like to see the lists in this way:

`0 Gen
01 Feb
02 Mar`

now I have a simple Adapter

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.month,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    monthSelector.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over your String arrays and concatenate the strings together. That would look something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> concatenated = new ArrayList<>();
String[] months = getResources().getStringArray(R.string.month);
String[] numbers = getResources().getStringArray(R.string.monthN);
for(int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
    concatenated.add(numbers[i] + " " + months[i]);
}
```

Now each element of `concatenated` will look like `NUMBER NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Month to appear in the spinner, and the selected value to be the number, try this:

```
 private void method name{
 ArrayList<dateStruct> datesArray = new ArrayList(dateStruct>();
 dateStruct = new dateStruct();
 String[] months = getResources().getStringArray(R.string.month);
 String[] numbers = getResources().getStringArray(R.string.monthN);
 // Build dates list and add to datesArray
 for(int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
    dateStruct.dateNumber = numbers[i];
    dateStruct.dateName = months[i];
    datesArray.add().dateStruct();
}

// bind to Spinner control
ArrayAdapter<dateStruct> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter< (MainActivity.this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, datesArray);
taskListDropdown_control.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}

 public class dateStruct
   {
      public String dateNumber;
      public String dataName;
   }
```